# Get file size of resized image using Codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm using CodeIgniter to upload an image on AWS S3.  However before I upload the image to S3 I want to resize it.  I'm using the native CodeIgniter image manipulation library to resize the image stored in the tmp folder on upload and then pushing this onto S3.  However after I have resized the image I want to get the new file size of the resized image but it keeps returning me the original image size before it was uploaded (using either CI file library or native PHP filesize function)

My code looks like:

```
 // set upload details
 $upload_details = array(
    'filename'          => $sanitized_filename,
    'location'          => $_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'],
    'size'              => $_FILES["file"]['size'],
    'extension'         => end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"])),
    'mime_type'         => get_file_mime_type($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']),
    's3_object_key'     => $s3_upload_path . $s3_filename,
    's3_upload_result'  => FALSE
 );

 // check if image we are uploading and if image options have been set
 $image_size = getimagesize($upload_details['location']);

 if($image_size)
 {
     $current_image_width = $image_size[0];
     $current_image_height = $image_size[1];

     if($current_image_width > $image_options['width'] || $current_image_height > $image_options['height'])
     {
         // specify image resize options
         $config['image_library']  = 'gd2';
         $config['source_image']   = $upload_details['location'];
         $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
         $config['width']          = $image_options['width'];
         $config['height']         = $image_options['height'];

         // load image manipulation library with config options
         $ci->load->library('image_lib', $config);

         if ( ! $ci->image_lib->resize())
         {
             showhouse_log(MY_Log::KERROR, $ci->image_lib->display_errors());
         }

         // update size details of new resized image
         $ci->load->helper('file');
         $info = get_file_info($upload_details['location'], array('size'));
         $new_file_size = filesize($upload_details['location']);
         $upload_details['size'] = $new_file_size;
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this isn't getting the new file size in the tmp directory even though I can see that the file size has changed on the tmp file in the flie system?

Comment: before check its size, try to verify if the file exists at first place. In some situations, the execution script does not wait to render the resized image.

Comment: When I debug this I have a breakpoint set on the line that does the resize. When I step over this and before I try to get the file size again I can see in the temp folder the size of the file has been reduced but if I continue on to get the updated file size again it returns the original. I've gotten around this by creating a new file after resizing and using this from that point onwards.